# Insert data input from form into multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have more about 5 tables, STUDENT, COURSE, DEPARTMENT, APPLICATION, ENROLMENT.

Student is applying online for a particular course by filling in form entring his personal details i.e. name, address, contact, etc and also choosing the department and particular course and then submitting the form.

I am not able to submit that form in other words not able to insert data typed in by student. Following are my tables.

STUDENT TABLE:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }        //PK
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppliedDate { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Applied> Applications { get; set; }
}
```

COURSE TABLE:

```
    public class Course
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }       //PK
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }   //FK
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string CoursCode { get; set; }
        public int NfqLevel { get; set; }
        public int CreditHrs { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Applied> Applications { get; set; }

    }
}
```

APPLIED TABLE:

```
public class Applied
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AppliedID { get; set; }      //PK
    public int StudentID { get; set; }      //FK
    public int CourseID { get; set; }       //FK
    public Status? ApplicationStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Enrolment Enrolment { get; set; }
}
```

MODELVIEW TABLE:

```
public class Application2
{      
    public int StudentID { get; set; }        //PK
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppliedDate { get; set; }
    public int? AppliedID { get; set; }      
    public int CourseID { get; set; }       
}
```

FOLLWING IS CONTROLLER PART:

```
public class Application2Controller : Controller
{
    private RegistrarsContext db = new RegistrarsContext();


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult DepartmentList()
    {
        var departments = db.Departments.OrderBy(x => x.DpName).ToList();
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(
                        departments,
                        "DepartmentID",
                        "DpName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
        }

        return View(departments);
    }

    public ActionResult CourseList(int DepartmentID)
    {
        var courses = db.Courses.Where(x => x.DepartmentID == DepartmentID).ToList();

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(new SelectList(courses, "CourseID", "CourseName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return View(courses);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Application2 application)

    {
        using (var db = new RegistrarsContext())

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            var student = new Student { StudentID = application.StudentID, FirstName = application.FirstName, LastName = application.LastName, DateOfBirth = application.DateOfBirth, Address = application.Address, PhoneNumber = application.PhoneNumber, Email = application.Email };


            var apply = new Applied { CourseID = application.CourseID, StudentID = application.StudentID };

                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.Applied.Add(apply);
        }

                      db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

FOLLOWING IS VIEW PART:

```
@model StudentsRegistration.ViewModels.Application2

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student Appication";
}

<h2>Student Application Form</h2>   

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student Details </h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }            <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentID)
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppliedDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppliedDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AppliedDate)
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Departments">Departments</label>
            <select id="Departments" name="Departments"></select>
        </div>
<br /><br /> 
        <div class="form-group">    
            <label for="Courses">Courses</label>
            <select id="Courses" name="Courses"></select>    
        </div>    
        @section scripts {
            <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Application2/Departments/List", function (data) {
                var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                    items += "<option value='" + country.Value + "'>" + country.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#Departments").html(items);
            });

            $("#Departments").change(function () {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("CourseList", "Application2")?DepartmentID=" + $("#Departments").val(), function (data) {
                    var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                        items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#Courses").html(items);
                });
            });
        });
            </script>
        }       

            <br /><br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: "i am not able to submit that form". so what happens instead? Do you get an error? Does the code take a different path when you debug it? There's a lot of code here, it would help people to answer if you could narrow down the problem a bit

Comment: on cliking submit button no error came up, but also no data get inseted as well. if someone could see controller CREAT method, i think problem is there.

Comment: have you debugged in visual studio? Is it hitting the controller action method?

Comment: i would be interested in seeing what HTML is rendered by `@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))` in your view. I wonder if it's pointing to the right place or not

Comment: Would u plz guid me how to debug. I press F5 and then i try to press F10 but nothing happen. I dont know how to debug in mvc

Comment: you need to set breakpoints at some point within the method and see if it reaches it. See this guide https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: and also please provide us the rendered output of `@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))` (by using View Source in your browser)